# When is the rank 2 free metabelian group of exponent $n$ center free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups

Let $M_n$ be the rank 2 free metabelian group of exponent $n$. For which $n$ is $M_n$ center-free?

The abelianization $M_n^{ab}\cong C_n\times C_n$, so the commutator subgroup $M_n'$ is a cyclic $(\mathbb{Z}/n)[C_n\times C_n]$-module (generated by the commutator of a generating pair of $M_n$), and one can show using the Magnus embedding that $M_n'$ can be identified with the quotient ring
$$R_n := (\mathbb{Z}/n)[x,y]/\langle 1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}\rangle_{a=x^iy^j}$$
where $a$ ranges over all elements of the form $x^iy^j$ for all $i,j$ (essentially, $a$ is the image of an element of $C_n\times C_n$ in the quotient map $(\mathbb{Z}/n)[C_n\times C_n]\rightarrow R_n$)

For $M_n$ to be center free, we first need to check that

1. No element outside $M_n'$ can act trivially on $M_n'$. This translates into $x^iy^j-1 = 0$ in $R_n$ if and only if $i\equiv j\equiv 0\mod n$.
2. No element in $M_n'$ is centralized by all elements of $M_n^{ab}$ (or equivalently a generating pair). This translates into $Ann_{R_n}(x-1)\cap Ann_{R_n}(y-1) = 0$

I'm having some difficulty analyzing this ring $R_n$.

Certainly if $n = p^r$, then $M_n$ is a $p$-group, and hence cannot be center-free. My feeling is that for "large enough $n$" which are sufficiently far from being prime powers, $M_n$ should be center-free. Is this true? If not, can we give conditions on $n$ for which $M_n$ is center-free? Preferably, for every integer $m$, I would like to find an $n$ with $m\mid n$ such that $M_n$ is center-free.

Comment: Have you checked a few specific values? e.g., of the form $n=pq$ for $p,q$ distinct primes? notably $n=6$?

Comment: I have actually just finished checking $n = 6$ (of order around 544000000), which took about 25 minutes on my computer to construct, and it seems to have a center of order 3.