# Is every finite 2-generated metabelian group the quotient of a finite 2-generated center-free metabelian group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

This is somewhat related to [When is the rank 2 free metabelian group of exponent $n$ center free?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279793/when-is-the-rank-2-free-metabelian-group-of-exponent-n-center-free)

Let $G$ be a finite 2-generated metabelian group. Can we construct a 2-generated finite metabelian group $P$ with $Z(P) = 1$ and a surjection $P\rightarrow G$?

It would be nice to be able to bound the exponent of $P$ in terms of that of $G$.